# how to optimise string search functionality using jquery or javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, search

how can the common English words can be ignored to only return keywords which can then be searched in MySQL database. for e.g. if a user types "Where can i find ice cream" it should return me keywords like "ice cream" where i can query it on MySQL.

Comment: There is no ready-made database of _common english words_, you know what they are, but you should program for the system to know too.

Comment: Of course there are lists of such words.  They are called "stop words" in the parlance of full text search.  Here is MySQL's list:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html.

Comment: in PHP there may be a list somewhere on the Net to download, u could use some logic when performing a search and cut the ones you dont need, like "Where" "I" "Can" "What" "Is" "When" "How" "Do" etc etc and put them in an array. PHP is server side so its lightning fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you looking for?

```
String.prototype.replaceArray = function(find, replace) {
var replaceString = this;
var regex;
for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
 regex = new RegExp(find[i], "g");
 replaceString = replaceString.replace(regex, replace[i]);
}
 return replaceString;
};

//usage
stop_words = ['silly','these','words', '  '];
//create an empty array as long as the first one
replace_them = ['','','',''];

var test = 'Some parts of this silly sentence will these words be replaced?'.replaceArray(stop_words,  replace_them);
console.log( test );
```

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/259579/bob

Comment: nice one, i'm not putting JQ down, good work, but what if you want around 10 thousand words to replace, isnt performance an issue. I never tried it to be honest so i don't know

Comment: Then i would definately do it in the backend. :)
but the list given here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html is small enough to do client side.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for StopWords :

```
$stopwords = array(“a”, “about”, “above”, “above”, “across”, “after”, “afterwards”, “again”, “against”, “all”, “almost”, “alone”, “along”, “already”, “also”,”although”,”always”,”am”,”among”, “amongst”, “amoungst”, “amount”,  “an”, “and”, “another”, “any”,”anyhow”,”anyone”,”anything”,”anyway”, “anywhere”, “are”, “around”, “as”,  “at”, “back”,”be”,”became”, “because”,”become”,”becomes”, “becoming”, “been”, “before”, “beforehand”, “behind”, “being”, “below”, “beside”, “besides”, “between”, “beyond”, “bill”, “both”, “bottom”,”but”, “by”, “call”, “can”, “cannot”, “cant”, “co”, “con”, “could”, “couldnt”, “cry”, “de”, “describe”, “detail”, “do”, “done”, “down”, “due”, “during”, “each”, “eg”, “eight”, “either”, “eleven”,”else”, “elsewhere”, “empty”, “enough”, “etc”, “even”, “ever”, “every”, “everyone”, “everything”, “everywhere”, “except”, “few”, “fifteen”, “fify”, “fill”, “find”, “fire”, “first”, “five”, “for”, “former”, “formerly”, “forty”, “found”, “four”, “from”, “front”, “full”, “further”, “get”, “give”, “go”, “had”, “has”, “hasnt”, “have”, “he”, “hence”, “her”, “here”, “hereafter”, “hereby”, “herein”, “hereupon”, “hers”, “herself”, “him”, “himself”, “his”, “how”, “however”, “hundred”, “ie”, “if”, “in”, “inc”, “indeed”, “interest”, “into”, “is”, “it”, “its”, “itself”, “keep”, “last”, “latter”, “latterly”, “least”, “less”, “ltd”, “made”, “many”, “may”, “me”, “meanwhile”, “might”, “mill”, “mine”, “more”, “moreover”, “most”, “mostly”, “move”, “much”, “must”, “my”, “myself”, “name”, “namely”, “neither”, “never”, “nevertheless”, “next”, “nine”, “no”, “nobody”, “none”, “noone”, “nor”, “not”, “nothing”, “now”, “nowhere”, “of”, “off”, “often”, “on”, “once”, “one”, “only”, “onto”, “or”, “other”, “others”, “otherwise”, “our”, “ours”, “ourselves”, “out”, “over”, “own”,”part”, “per”, “perhaps”, “please”, “put”, “rather”, “re”, “same”, “see”, “seem”, “seemed”, “seeming”, “seems”, “serious”, “several”, “she”, “should”, “show”, “side”, “since”, “sincere”, “six”, “sixty”, “so”, “some”, “somehow”, “someone”, “something”, “sometime”, “sometimes”, “somewhere”, “still”, “such”, “system”, “take”, “ten”, “than”, “that”, “the”, “their”, “them”, “themselves”, “then”, “thence”, “there”, “thereafter”, “thereby”, “therefore”, “therein”, “thereupon”, “these”, “they”, “thickv”, “thin”, “third”, “this”, “those”, “though”, “three”, “through”, “throughout”, “thru”, “thus”, “to”, “together”, “too”, “top”, “toward”, “towards”, “twelve”, “twenty”, “two”, “un”, “under”, “until”, “up”, “upon”, “us”, “very”, “via”, “was”, “we”, “well”, “were”, “what”, “whatever”, “when”, “whence”, “whenever”, “where”, “whereafter”, “whereas”, “whereby”, “wherein”, “whereupon”, “wherever”, “whether”, “which”, “while”, “whither”, “who”, “whoever”, “whole”, “whom”, “whose”, “why”, “will”, “with”, “within”, “without”, “would”, “yet”, “you”, “your”, “yours”, “yourself”, “yourselves”, “the”);
```

There is no complete stop words dictionary, but you can search about stop words and improve this dictionary.